# CSS classes have no effect on Quill Editor classes Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, quill

I'm trying to add CSS to my quill editor, but no CSS is applied in any class.

Below is my template

```
<div class="container">
      <form [formGroup]="editForm">
        <quill-editor  [modules] = "config" 
        (onEditorChanged) = "onContentChange($event)" formControlName="editor"></quill-editor>  
      </form>             
</div>
```

AS clearly you can see this includes classes like ql-editor and ql-toolbar (below Image)
[image]

so i apply CSS to those classes and it won't work.
Below is my CSS

```
.container .ql-editor{
    width : 8.5in;
    min-height:   11in;
    padding: 1in;
    margin: 1 rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background-color: white;
}

.container .ql-container.ql-snow{
border:none;
display:flex;
justify-content: center;   
}
```

Comment: It depends on other styles as well. If you can reproduce this demo on Codesandbox or any other platform, people can debug the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since quill-editor component styles are encapsulated you need to move these styles to style.css or you need to use ::ng-deep

```
  ::ng-deep .container .ql-editor{
        width : 8.5in;
        min-height:   11in;
        padding: 1in;
        margin: 1 rem;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        background-color: white;
    }
    
    ::ng-deep .container .ql-container.ql-snow{
     border:none;
     display:flex;
     justify-content: center;   
    }
```